# Generic T GetByID<K>(K ID_)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, repository-pattern

I'm trying to implement a generic repository using the entity framework.

My repository is defined as :

```
    public class GenericRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
```

I want to add a generic GetByID where the type of ID being passed in is generic too. I don't really want my business logic to tell me the type is e.g....

```
    _repository.GetByID<int>(123);
```

I want to hide the tyoe definition but can't figure out where or how to do this.

Most posts on Stackoverflow seem to just have their ID's as ints. I don't want this as your identifiers aren't always going to be ints!

Any ideas on this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did this

```
interface IRepository<TEntity, TKey> {
     TEntity GetById(TKey id);
}
```

Then I inherit from this interface

```
class Person {
     int ID;
}
interface IPersonRepository : IRepository<Person, int> { ... }
```

This makes it very DI/IoC and Unit Testing friendly too.

Comment: +1, was just typing the same thing.  I have used this several times with no problems.

Comment: Virtual -1. This again does not address the main issue asked in the question. BL still needs to know the type and **the generics here is wrong** because only one type of key is acceptable.

Comment: Well i'm not sure how generics are required here for TKey. In 99% of cases, e.g excluding weird PK fields and composite keys, the PK will be a identity (int). So `GetById(int id)` is sufficient. I don't see the need for `TKey`.

Answer (score 1):

I have defined ID as `object` in my `IRepository`. Sometimes it is `int`, sometimes `Guid` and sometimes `string`.

**It is sub-optimal but it works.**

```
interface IRepository<T>
{
    T GetById(object id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a method as accepting a type:

`var t = new Thing();`

`t.GetById<int>(44);`

where

```
public class Thing
{
public void GetById<T>(T id)
{
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overloading?:

```
T GetByID(int anint) {
    return GetByID<int>(anint);
}
```

Comment: Virtual -1. Clients will be using the interface and not the actual class to communicate so would not have access to it.

Comment: What is this Virtual -1 nonsense? Are you trying to say answers are unhelpful but don't want to lose the 1 rep point?